# Images from Docker compose not working as expected when running from docker run command

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have few micro-services built using Spring boot which are

- Service Discovery
- Gateway Server or Zuul Proxy Server
- A backend application which serves the REST API's

The following is part of the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  st-service-registry:
    build:
      context: service-registry/
      args:
        VERSION: ${VERSION}
    restart: on-failure
    image: st/service-registry:${VERSION}
    container_name: st-service-registry
    ports:
      - 8180:8180
    tty: true
    networks:
      - st-network

  st-backend:
    build:
      context: backend/
      args:
        VERSION: ${VERSION}
    restart: on-failure
    image: st/backend:${VERSION}
    environment:
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://st-service-registry:8180/eureka
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - redis
      - st-service-registry
      - st-gateway-server
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
    networks:
      - st-network

  st-gateway-server:
    build:
      context: gateway-server/
      args:
        VERSION: ${VERSION}
    restart: on-failure
    image: st/gateway-server:${VERSION}
    container_name: st-gateway-server
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - st-service-registry
    networks:
      - st-network

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ${MONGO_DB_DATA_LOCATION}:/data/db
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - st-network

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - st-network

networks:
  st-network:
    driver: bridge
```

When I run the entire stack using `docker-compose up --build` everything works perfect. I can see the docker images and I can run the microservices and stuff like that. But when I try to run individual images using `docker run -itd -p 8080:8080 _image_Id_` the micro-service cannot connect to the service registry. It says **Connection Refused**

Do you guys have any lead on this? Let me know if you need any other information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Below property has to be corrected:

```
   environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://st-service-registry:8180/eureka
```

Sample docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  eureka-server:
    image: barathece91/eureka-server-demo
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - st-network
  eureka-client-app1:
    image: barathece91/eureka-client-demo
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    networks:
      - st-network
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://eureka-server:8081/eureka    

networks:
  st-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this **eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone** was working fine when I use docker-compose. The issue I have is when I run each container manually.

Answer (score 0):

try setting `--name as container-name and --hostname as container-name` for all the container's that you are going to generate

The point is when you create containers manually - it will set container-name or hostname auto-generated.

Services looking up each other by their name (container-name)

for example:

```
docker run -d --name st-service-registry \
              --hostname st-service-registry \
              --network st-network \
              --restart=on-failure \
              -p 8180:8180 \
              st/service-registry:${VERSION}

docker run -d --name redis \
              --hostname redis \
              --network st-network \
              --restart=always \
              -p 6379:6379 \
              redis
docker run -d --name mongo \
              --hostname mongo \
              --network st-network \
              --restart=always \
              -p 27017:27017 \
              mongo

docker run -d --name st-gateway-server \
              --hostname st-gateway-server \
              --network st-network \
              --restart=on-failure \
              -p 8080:8080 \
              st/gateway-server:${VERSION}


docker run -d --name st-service-registry \
              --hostname st-service-registry \
              -e eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://st-service-registry:8180/eureka \
              --network st-network \
              -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone \
              -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime \
              st/backend:${VERSION}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me try this.

Comment: I still have the same issue, it still says connection refused :(

Comment: try following command to see if machine is reachable or not. `docker run --rm 
 st/backend:$VERSION ping st-service-registry`

Comment: I tried `docker run --rm st/backend:$VERSION ping st-service-registry` still same connection refused.

Comment: come over chat section

Comment: I'm sorry that I need to have 20 reputation points to access chat section :(

Comment: I figured out the solution. I have added --link and --hostname to the `docker run` command and now everything seems to be working. Thanks your time.

Comment: Good Job,  Ideally docker containers on the same (declared network) will be able to identify using there container names.

Comment: yes, but somehow on my machine it was not working. So I have to add `--link` & `--hostname` to `docker run`. Your help is appreciated.